# SSIS Loop container rename file name on a Monday

Tags: ssis

I am busy setting up an SSIS, I am using a foreach/loop container to get a csv, it places it in a staging SQL, I then do my normalization with joins, push to production, archive my files again with a loopcontainer and variables and clean up my staging enviroment.

All working perfectly, except on a Monday (or after a off day,) my files have the same name everyday and I am adding a time stamp.

The issue is getting the files after an off day i need too get 2 files or more, Windows adds a incrementing number in brackets and although I can get this file imported, I cannot get the rename loop to find this file (I will add my move to staging and rename are in different dtsx steps,) as a result these files are not renamed and then not move to archive.

I am guessing the issue is my filename variable as it is static, IO likely need a wildcard FileImport.csv is my normal file and my variable but I sometimes have FileImport (1).csv and likely need something equivilent to FileImport*.csv.

Answer (score 1):

[Source Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p90bL.png)

Figured it out, firstly fix the connection to point at the folder, then instead of using a variable to for the source connection, use the connection manager, working as intended now